# sendmail appending domain on top of another domain

Tags: sendmail

Need your help in sendmail, as im stuck with this issue for more than a week.

Currently im facing issue with sendmail in RHEL5.9 OS

i have my sendmail configured to send email to outside world.

And the issue is, whenever im sending email to 1 particular domain, the sendmail is adding default DNS domain along with it

DNS entry in /etc/resolv.conf 
-->
search domain1.business1.com

for example when im sending email to ->

"test1@hostname.domain2.business1.com.cn", in /var/log/maillog, i can see that, the email is sending as -> test1@hostname.domain2.business1.com.cn.domain1.business1.com.

Any idea ?

For other emails, or domain surprisingly its working OK. even for outside email like gmail and yahoo.

If you need any other input, do let me know, and thanks in advance for reading this.

Comment: Is your sendmail sendmail?

Comment: What do you see in the Sendmail logs?

Comment: in  log can see as below.. Since comment have character limitation, adding the line by line in 3 comments

Comment: May 15 14:52:11 test-a sendmail[29031]: t4F6qBDP029031: from=<root@test-a.dept1.company.com.sg>, size=430, class=0, nrcpts=2, msgid=<201505150652.t4F6qBw3029030@test-a.dept1.company.com.sg>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1]

Comment: May 15 14:52:11 test-a sendmail[29030]: t4F6qBw3029030: to=user1@sg.company.com,alarm@smsgateway.dept2.company.com.sg, ctladdr=root (0/0), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=60107, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (t4F6qBDP029031 Message accepted for delivery)

Comment: May 15 14:52:40 test-a sendmail[29033]: t4F6qBDP029031: to=<alarm@smsgateway.dept2.company.com.sg.dept1.company.com.sg>,<user1@sg.company.com>, ctladdr=<root@test-a.dept1.company.com.sg> (0/0), delay=00:00:29, xdelay=00:00:29, mailer=relay, pri=150430, relay=relay-a.mei.co.sg. [XXX.X.X.XX], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (t4F6oSM10972 Message accepted for delivery)